# List all bundle types for entity field query?

Tags: 7, entities, database

Trying to use entity field query to simplify some times; e.g. a slide show of images.

How does one get the field values for entity field query. Specifically, get a list of all the possible bundle types there are?

E.g.

```
<?php

function foo_load() {
   $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
   $query
     // What conditions or properties are there?
     ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
     ->entityCondition('bundle', 'banner')
     ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC');
     ->propertyCondition('status', 1);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as per your example code you are just concerned with nodes then the bundles are just your node types.

If you want to get a list of node types you can use:

[node_type_get_types()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_types/7)
or
[node_type_get_names()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_names/7)

You can get the bundles from the array keys of the arrays returned from those functions.